# Transaction reverted by the EVM and I cannot see the reason

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-design, contract-debugging, solidity-0.8.x

I am new to blockchain technology and ethereum contracts development and I cannot track down the bug I have in my first contract code.

This is an ERC-721 (NFT) contract type. NFT is a reward for finishing a simple game.  The game is about finding twenty secret `stationIDs` (QR codes) and sending `mintNFT(stationID)` twenty times, writing ones' 'visit' to the `stationId` on the blockchain. Once all stations have been visited, ones' dApp displays information to visit one last place and receive one of the unique 1021 coin codes. After sending `mintNFT` with ones' unique coin code, one actually performs the final minting and becomes an owner of the NFT.

I have been playing around with this contract a bit and it seemed to work fine (despite it being dirty and non-optimal). I have played the game with nine different account addresses from start to end (got nine NFTs), and with several more accounts I have visited random stations but did not complete the game. At one point though, the contract started hitting `Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM` every time I send `mintNFT` with any `stationID` from any account. When I call `mintNFT` with unique coin code, the transaction succeeds.

I've ruled-out reasons like: incorrect nonce, insufficient funds, hitting gasLimit or abi mismatch. My best bet is the bug is triggered in `visitStation` function and is memory-related.
Sadly I did not manage to reproduce the bug in tests...

This is all in a geth local network with PoA (clique, period 5s). In the geth logs i can see: `Skipping transaction with low nonce` every time the EVM reverts the transaction.

My main question is: **Can you help me spot the bug?**

Obviously the code needs improvements and I would also love to get some hints for optimising things like:

- storing both `bytes arrays` and `mappings` with those addresses - I am sure there should be a way to traverse mappings keys, so that storing bytes arrays wouldn't be necessary
- storing the hashes of the `stationIDs` and coin codes that I expect in the game (I store hashes to hide them from users who could read and understand the contract to cheat)
- building the NFT URI
- contract creation and execution gas costs

Contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract MyContract is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    bytes32[20] public stationHashes;
    bytes32[1021] coinHashes;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint8) stations;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint16) coins;

    mapping(address => uint16) public mintedId;

    mapping(address => mapping(uint8 => bool)) public stationVisits;
    mapping(uint16 => address) public minterOf;
    bool public gameOver = false;

    event Visit(address who, uint8 visitedStationNumber);
    event Minted(address who, uint16 mintedTokenID);

    constructor() ERC721("MyContract", "My Test Contract") {
        stationHashes = [
            bytes32(0x1d26366121c3aabab711a189a0de050ce92b92c982389163002a7e4f9e8ef653),
            bytes32(0xfccd6b209bcfb6e20dac4fe71b988ba0a314dd1b4da61d60c8eb7683e4b0178a),
            bytes32(0xcc50ea6ddf8a47574106eec2641e50f00c6d7df1b0d6df9ec010f4b6e1b25ddc),
            bytes32(0x6359291ee2e7724c33af04ca49b7dcf2a321131bb56e573ea81c4c58b25cfc3e),
            bytes32(0xf20038617e01efb9e4a62274839e4ab005cbfffcef8f86fad90839820a67ccf7),
            bytes32(0x5f57fe95cdd1bc58b268cc27c1280b6e4fb4320454e4cfeab158e8338787c8d4),
            bytes32(0x9c8f238d4fbd217adfffebbaba3b8d3be7219fa79d05baf8d57afa70d835bd56),
            bytes32(0x7ffc2e2749570dea05b75741e7c75031085108c31e5094d00efedda56c25c1d0),
            bytes32(0x27c2f5f3478b2f2e11a289525cb4cd6c516a5cae1f95bdfc64745a73a8afb651),
            bytes32(0x91fb80a1a04dd0b54c9a402ef768e542a8b6e2b6aa20d889e995520a7d1199c0),
            bytes32(0xe6954ff30cd440b2e1d0a6157669c69d7269d0b656415ef98a3db7e81d26b481),
            bytes32(0xa5faff17265cf386297fb727566325f204af84b824bdd0b6d22ad4c0dc4c8aa6),
            bytes32(0x25f5b18d9f9b104ef2f8ef383a171e05ee325527d94d897b7b735f08e401fdc7),
            bytes32(0x4d787d8667a69bce40399cb0275152eed7b4764c6bfa94cd29a1cd1ce50997b5),
            bytes32(0xe3643afaec2d0b525736472e3f3030310b43d5c0fc39ffb4cabbd7359b392b93),
            bytes32(0x1b273c210d74f0a99d7064236caad9122fddf9cb16b16b307b500ef10f2f3efa),
            bytes32(0x717fd153babbc26a5bf673ec2e21d436df01825bad59a161fe0a40b2611c471c),
            bytes32(0x1f3c3ff91ed7c60b1452ec1829504e0c86f2d28b71f5aa3534f0811c872e95fe),
            bytes32(0x2079cf73ab7db58d344c5a049d2896ffe94c01742a8365ce50e1def196002da2),
            bytes32(0x3827791103ebcbd5c389d96028305625ba65636206b4dfe68be91e3733edb389)
        ];

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            stations[stationHashes[i]] = i + 1;
        }

        coinHashes = [
            bytes32(0x2e34f5e1e3a9cf2cce3a3d77cf84e32ff75eb58705ca0581e7d86a6b997a906a),
            bytes32(0xbe166e23a34b65f5e2ac33f63a58fefaf90dd6362316f6f139b579f3692f4e68),
            bytes32(0x45da73bdf0bb52c2fb7cf02f56e609b13a3af7b4d2e4bb5706b8581f78080188)
            // ... 1018 more hashes here
        ];

        for (uint16 i = 0; i < 1021; i++) {
            coins[coinHashes[i]] = i + 1;
        }
    }

    function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory _uintAsString) {
        if (_i == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint j = _i;
        uint len;
        while (j != 0) {
            len++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint k = len;
        while (_i != 0) {
            k = k-1;
            uint8 temp = (48 + uint8(_i - _i / 10 * 10));
            bytes1 b1 = bytes1(temp);
            bstr[k] = b1;
            _i /= 10;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }

    function getVisits(address recipient) public view returns (bool[21] memory visited) {
        for (uint8 id = 1; id <= 21; id++) {
            visited[id - 1] = stationVisits[recipient][id];
        }
        return visited;
    }

    function getMinters() public view returns (address[1021] memory tokenMinters) {
        for (uint16 i = 0; i < 1021; i++) {
            tokenMinters[i] = minterOf[i + 1];
        }
        return tokenMinters;
    }

    function visitStation(address recipient, string memory stationID) private {
        uint8 stationNo = stationNumber(stationID);
        if (stationNo > 0 && !stationVisits[recipient][stationNo]) {
            stationVisits[recipient][stationNo] = true;
            emit Visit(recipient, stationNo);
        }
        uint16 coinNumber = coins[stationHash(stationID)];
        if (coinNumber > 0 && !stationVisits[recipient][21]) {
            stationVisits[recipient][21] = true;
        }
    }

    function isFinalMinting() public view returns (bool) {
        bool visited = true;
        for (uint8 id = 1; id <= 21; id++) {
            visited = visited && stationVisits[msg.sender][id];
        }
        return visited;
    }

    function stationHash(string memory stationID) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return sha256(abi.encode(stationID));
    }

    function stationNumber(string memory stationID) public view returns (uint8) {
        bytes32 hash = stationHash(stationID);
        if (stations[hash] > 0) {
            return stations[hash];
        } else if (coins[hash] > 0) {
            return 21;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function setGameOver(bool value) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        gameOver = value;
        return gameOver;
    }


    function mintNFT(string memory stationID) public returns (uint16) {
        require(mintedId[msg.sender] == 0, 'Single user may mint one item only!');
        uint16 coinId = coins[stationHash(stationID)];
        require(minterOf[coinId] == address(0), 'This coin has already been minted!');
        require(_tokenIds.current() < 1021, 'Game is over, 1021 coins have been minted!');
        require(gameOver == false, "Time's up! The Game is over, sorry!");

        visitStation(msg.sender, stationID);

        if (isFinalMinting()){
            _tokenIds.increment();
            
            _safeMint(msg.sender, coinId);
            
            _setTokenURI(coinId, string(abi.encodePacked("https://supersecretlink/", uint2str(coinId), ".json")));
            
            mintedId[msg.sender] = coinId;
            minterOf[coinId] = msg.sender;
            emit Minted(msg.sender, coinId);

            return coinId;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

geth 1.10.8-stable-26675454

dApps dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@ethereum-waffle/chai": "^3.4.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.2",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.3.2",
    "@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades": "^1.10.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.0",
    "ethers": "^5.4.7",
    "hardhat": "^2.6.4",
    "hardhat-contract-sizer": "^2.1.1",
    "mocha": "^9.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@alch/alchemy-web3": "^1.1.4",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "truffle-flattener": "^1.5.0",
    "waffle": "^0.0.4",
    "web3": "^1.5.2"
  }
```

Comment: Have you been writing this code? If not, please include any relevant SPDX-Licence in your source.

Comment: " In the geth logs i can see: Skipping transaction with low nonce every time the EVM reverts the transaction." -> do you specify a nonce ? How are you calling mint() ?

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth the code is mine except for the uint2str conversion which is a [SO copy-paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65707309/2838339). I do not really know how to go about this, can you help?

Comment: Also @DrGorilla.eth I do specify a nonce returned by `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PUBLIC_KEY)` and it is a correct one.
I'm signing transaction first, and then sendingSignedTransaction.
I already found a bug, and it was an issue with the contract logic. Will add an answer soon! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a logical bug in the contract code. When one sent `mintNFT` with unique coin code before 'visiting' all stationIDs (out-of-sequence), 'visiting' the last station ended with minting a `coinId == 0`.
All subsequent `mintNFT(stationId)` calls failed at:

```
uint16 coinId = coins[stationHash(stationID)];
require(minterOf[coinId] == address(0), 'This coin has already been minted!');
```

because `coinId` equals zero and `minterOf[0]` is the address of a wallet that did the out-of-sequence `mintNFT` calls.

Either way, I still leave the question open, as I would really like to get optimisation hints!